# html select list - get the displayed text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, html-select

I have a bootstrap modal confirm pop up connected to a form submit button where I want to include the current text value displayed in a html select list as well as the selected text value of the same html select list.

For example, I have the following html select list:

```
<select name="test_list" id="id_test_list">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four" selected="selected">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
</select>
```

To add the modal message to the submit button, I have the following code:

```
$( "#submit_buttonA" ).attr('update-confirm', 'From ' + $('#id_test_list option:selected').text() + ' to ' + $('#id_test_list').text());
```

The modal message is displayed as:

```
From One to One Two Three Four Five
```

How do I change the code of the 2nd text value **$('#id_test_list').text()** to display only the current text value of the html select list?

For example, the user has displayed the option value two (Two) in the html select list (but the selected value is still option value four).

```
From Four to Two
```

**EDIT**
I have just realized what I have asked here! This is the effect of being sleep deprived and looking at a problem for too long and over thinking the issue.
Sorry to all for asking such a deranged question.

Comment: I dont get it -- selected and current are the same thing in an HTML select?

Comment: i think you should save recent selecting value into a variable, then update it after

Comment: I don't understand your question either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. but as you want the current or selected value of the select you can use

```
$( "#submit_buttonA" ).attr('update-confirm', 'From ' + $('#id_test_list option:selected').text() + ' to ' + $('#id_test_list').val());
```

Change `text()` to `val()`

---

Alternatively you can also use

```
$('#id_test_list :selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `.text()` to `.val()`.

```
$('#id_test_list').val();
```

Comment: no this does not return the text value of the select list as stated in the question.

Comment: its dropDown and not a input box

Comment: Sorry, Mohit - I think we submitted at the same time.  My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

replace

## submit_buttonA

to this

## id_test_list

Comment: no this is not correct. the submit_buttonA must be used, else I would be adding the code to the select list. Must be connected to the submit button as stated in the question.